# Can't figure out how to translate an <input type="checkbox"> to a PHP boolean

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have an `<input type="checkbox" name="showonhmpg" />` which I want to become a PHP `true`/`false` value depending on whether it is checked. For some reason, I've noticed that if it's checked then `$_POST['showonhmpg']` equals `0` and if it's not checked then `$_POST['showonhmpg']` equals `null`. Is this expected behavior? It's awkward because then I have to write something like

```
$showonhmpg = $_POST['showonhmpg'] ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checkboxes that are unchecked won't be sent to the server, you can use `isset`:

```
$showonhmpg = isset($_POST['showonhmpg']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unchecked radio or checkbox elements are not submitted. So you have to check if they are sent, using the `isset` or `empty` function.

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    // whether checkbox checked
}
```

or using ternary:

```
isset($_POST['checkbox'])?true:false
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['checkbox'])?$_POST['checkbox']:false` would give you values of either 'ON' (string) or `false` not `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is expected.
If you want to secure that $_POST['showonhmpg'] contains a value, you can apply the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="showonhmpg" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="showonhmpg" value="1" />
```

In order to get a true/false value in your PHP code:
    $showonhmpg = (bool) $_POST['showonhmpg'];

Comment: This is completely and totally wrong on so many levels. Take a look at the other answers.

Comment: Then please explain why it should be wrong? This way you can avoid isset... there are many ways.

Comment: With your silly method, when the checkbox is not set the query string is `?showonhmpg=0` and when it is checked the query string is `?showonhmpg=0&showonhmpg=1` so its more complicated than just checking isset because now you have two values for the same parameter.

Comment: Your hack works, amazingly, but only if you make sure to put the hidden input first. If you reverse the order, like `<input type="checkbox" name="showonhmpg" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="showonhmpg" value="0" />` then you get a query string of `?showonhmpg=1&showonhmpg=0` when the checkbox is checked, and of course, `$_POST['showonhmpg']` gives you the last one.

Comment: Sorry for the error. I've edited my post. In my opinion this hack has one big advantage: if you want to save the value into a database, you don't need constructs like:
   `code` if (!isset($_POST['showonhmpg'])) {
        $_POST['showonhmpg'] = 0
   }`code`